# Elastix: is there a way to setup a conference with infinite duration?

Tags: infinite, duration, conference, elastix

Elastix: is there a way to setup a conference with infinite duration?  Cause when I create it from the Elastix web manager they only last some days and they dissapear

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create the conference under the **PBX Configuration** tab and not the **Conferences** tab.

Then it's permanent and won't disappear.